# Creating a new project to access old project firestore database due to URL issues

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a firebase project and app with Firestore database and hosting. After completing everything, I have noticed the url has some integer alphabet set which I don't want. I haven't noticed this while making the project as this was my first project. So I created a new project with a good project name, so the url is clean without any integer or Id. But I was not able to transfer data from the old project Firestore database to this new one.

Is it OK to use the Firestore database of old project in the new project app or should I use the Firestore database of the new one ? Because, I don't see any option to import Firestore database without a premium plan.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a database from a Firestore project with another project. You can try to recreate the data by yourself in the new project or upgrading your plan to a premium one.

To transfer data from a Firestore project to another project you have to follow [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data):

1. Enable billing for your project (this will upgrade you to a premium plan).
2. Set the correct permissions to your account.
3. Export data from the source project [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data#export_data_from_the_source_project).
4. Import data into the destination project [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/move-data#import_data_into_the_destination_project).

Comment: So you are saying that I cannot use the database connection of another firestore project I own, in another project ?

Comment: You can do it if you do the export/import procedure, but that implies enable billing in your project. Is worth noting that you don't have to pay anything if you are still under [the limits](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).